# How to redirect traffic from squid to vpn?

Tags: vpn, routing, proxy, squid

I have a windows machine with a squid server and VPN client connection(which is not the default gateway)

What I want is to redirect some traffic from squid to my default ethernet connection and some to VPN.

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1

PPP adapter vpn_conn:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.3.33
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

squid conf

```
http_port 2003
acl  user3_acl  myport 2003
tcp_outgoing_address 172.16.3.33 user3_acl

http_port 2004
acl  user4_acl  myport 2004
```

2004 port works as expected through my Ethernet adapter, but redirect to vpn doesn't work,

the log contains

```
1638648992.630     75 33.33.333.333 NONE/503 0 CONNECT docs.microsoft.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
```

Comment: You will still need a route on the VPN interface so that any outgoing traffic has a destination, but with a high metric it should not be used by anything by default

Comment: Thank you, it's true. I've managed to solve it with `route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 172.16.3.33`. But can you explain to me how it works? As far as I understand tcp_outgoing_address  should send traffic to VPN link, and then it will be routed further. Why do I need to specify an additional route?

Comment: It wants to go out on that interface yes, but where should the traffic go, it has no route other than that network. So what should it do to reach something like 8.8.8.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still needs a route on the VPN interface so that any outgoing traffic has a destination, but with a high metric it should not be used by anything by default.

Since it is link on 172.16.3.33 it knows how to reach that and the peer, but nothing else, so it will be unreachable.

Now adding that route allows it to know where to go for any other traffic. There might be an additional step needed, and that is for the other side to know how the traffic will find its way back, but since you are using proxy with local source, that will be mostly covered.